# Altering w3 example table filter to search multiple columns

Tags: javascript, php, html, filter, html-table

I am working in PHP with a large table of alternating amounts of columns per row. The rows and columns are generated and populated by a series of "foreach" loops calling things from a MYSQL database.

I'm pretty comfortable with the PHP/HTML and MYSQL end of things.

I'm attempting to use Javascript to create some "quick filters" for this table.

I started from an example on w3 which is as follows

```
    <script> 
     function myFunction() {
 // Declare variables 
  var input, filter, table, tr, td, i;
 input = document.getElementById("myInput");
 filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
 table = document.getElementById("myTable");
 tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");

 // Loop through all table rows, and hide those who don't match the 
search query
 for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
if (td) {
  if (td.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
    tr[i].style.display = "";
  } else {
    tr[i].style.display = "none";
  }
 } 
}
}
</script>
```

This works alongside an input tag where you can search with user input text. Mine doesn't look example like the example anymore, but my real question is

How can I make this search through ALL the columns (effectively the entire text of the table) as its written, this section of code controls which column is searched.

```
 td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
```

the [0] at the end means it searches the "first" column only. changing the 0 to another number will change to searching the corresponding column of the whole table.

I feel like there must be a simple way to expand this to multiple columns. I am completely new to JS so I'm really fumbling around here.

I've tried all the basic things I could think of like just changing the number around stuff like:

```
[0,1,2,3,4]// [0-4]// [0][1][2]
```

None of those simple things seem to be what I'm looking for. It either picks the last listed number for the column to search, or just breaks it altogether!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to nest loops!
I had to use an extra variable *occurrence* to check if an occurrence is in any td of the same row.
So if not, the row can be hidden!

```
  function myFunction() {
      // Declare variables 
      var input, filter, table, tr, td, i, occurrence;

      input = document.getElementById("myInput");
      filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
      table = document.getElementById("myTable");
      tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");

      // Loop through all table rows, and hide those who don't match the search query
     for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
         occurrence = false; // Only reset to false once per row.
         td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td");
         for(var j=0; j< td.length; j++){                
             currentTd = td[j];
             if (currentTd ) {
                 if (currentTd.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
                     tr[i].style.display = "";
                     occurrence = true;
                 } 
             }
         }
         if(!occurrence){
             tr[i].style.display = "none";
         } 
     }
   }
```

currentTd[j] is what you were looking for!
But since you may don't know how many td are in a row, you have to use the for loop!